# how to fix this problem geolocator_android:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'

Tags: flutter

I tried several solutions but it didn't work

I use dependencies pubspec.yaml

```
geolocator: ^8.0.5

flutter clean
cd android ./gradlew clean
flutter pub get
```

and I've made changes to build.gradle

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 31

    defaultConfig {
       
        applicationId "id.co.do.lol"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 31
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }
}
```

i use flutter sdk 2.8.1 and dart sdk 2.15.1

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
 versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
 versionName flutterVersionName
```

to

```
versionCode 1
versionName '1.01'
```